# Why am I getting an extra thread running in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm working with a Raspberry Pi.

I have a button connected to a GPIO pin, and an LED connected to a different pin. When the button is pressed, a function is called.
While that function is active, I want the LED to blink, which requires a background thread. This essentially means I need a background thread to run while my button handler is running, and to stop when my button handler stops.

The problem I'm having is demonstrated by running the code below. The code starts out with a single thread, but when I hit the button, threading.active_count() shows that there are 3 threads running (not 2 as expected). When my thread is done running, I'm left with 2 background threads - not 1 as expected.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread, Event

#########################
# Function to Blink LED #
#########################

# Sample function that blinks the LED
def blink_led_func(led, stop_blinking):
    while not stop_blinking.is_set():
        print("Blinking LED...")
        time.sleep(0.5)

#############
# Decorator #
#############

# Starts a background thread which blinks the LED, runs the decorated
# function, and when the function is done running, stops blinking the LED
class blink_led:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.f = function

    def __call__(self, channel):
        stop = Event()
        t = Thread(target=blink_led_func, args=(1, stop))
        t.start()

        self.f(channel)

        stop.set()
        t.join()

##################
# Button Handler #
##################

# Called when button is pressed
@blink_led
def btn_handler(channel):
    print("Button pressed")
    time.sleep(5)

##############
# Setup GPIO #
##############

# Setup pin
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

##############################
# Add Button Event Listeners #
##############################

GPIO.add_event_detect(12, GPIO.FALLING, callback=btn_handler, bouncetime=300)

########
# Main #
########

print("Listening for button presses...")

i = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("%s threads running" % threading.active_count())
```

This is the output of my code:

```
Listening for button presses...
1 threads running
1 threads running
1 threads running
Blinking LED...
Button pressed
3 threads running
Blinking LED...
Blinking LED...
3 threads running
Blinking LED...
Blinking LED...
3 threads running
Blinking LED...
Blinking LED...
3 threads running
Blinking LED...
Blinking LED...
3 threads running
Blinking LED...
Blinking LED...
Button pressed
3 threads running
Blinking LED...
Blinking LED...
3 threads running
Blinking LED...
Blinking LED...
3 threads running
Blinking LED...
Blinking LED...
3 threads running
Blinking LED...
Blinking LED...
3 threads running
Blinking LED...
2 threads running
2 threads running
2 threads running
```

This is tripping me up because in my real code, I have a Ctrl+C handler that says: use a threading.Event() to signal all threads to die, wait until `active_count() == 1` (only the main thread is left), clean up GPIO and exit. This should, in theory, prevent background threads from trying to use the GPIO library to blink after it gets cleaned up (which would cause an exception), but in practice, it gets stuck waiting for the other threads to die, as there's always 2 for some reason.

Did I do something wrong? Or does the GPIO library do something funky?

Edit: If I comment out the `GPIO.add_event_detect` line and add a manual call to my btn_handler function instead (`btn_handler(1)`), I don't have this problem. After the function is done running, I'm down to 1 thread according to `active_count()`. Whatever the problem is, it seems to be related to me starting a thread in a GPIO event handler function.

Also note that if I don't start a background thread in the btn_handler, `active_count()` remains at 1 the entire run, so as far as I can tell, the GPIO library isn't running any background threads.

Edit 2: Also note that when I'm down to 2 running threads (when I only expect there to be one), if I add code to check the names of the threads, the extra thread is called "Dummy-3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`RPi.GPIO`'s event handling is performed in a dedicated thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/#threaded-callbacks) launched implicitly to handle executing callbacks:

> RPi.GPIO runs a second thread for callback functions. This means that callback functions can be run at the same time as your main program, in immediate response to an edge.

There is only ever one of these threads, no matter how many callbacks are registered:

> [T]he callback functions are run sequentially, not concurrently. This is because there is only one thread used for callbacks, in which every callback is run, in the order in which they have been defined.

Comment: It seems strange to me that until I actually press a button, and my btn_handler is triggered, there's only one thread (according to active_count()) - the main thread. If there's a separate thread that RPi.GPIO is running that watches for an edge, and calls callback functions, shouldn't it be running as soon as you register the first callback function using `GPIO.add_event_detect`?

Comment: @John: I don't know the internals, but at a guess, the actual events are interrupt based, but to avoid causing issues with the main thread, when the main thread receives an interrupt tied to a callback, it just queues the event callback info up. If no event processing thread exists, one is launched when the first event with a callback occurs to begin processing the queue.